# nvidia (proprietary) output not resuming after suspend

Tags: xorg, nvidia, manjaro, lightdm, multiseat

After suspend+resume, the display connected to my NVidia card (3050 ti) with proprietary drivers on Manjaro keeps getting 'no signal' about 95% of the times. All of the standard tricks (updating bios, toggling nvidia-drm.modeset, various other kernel flags, various XOrg options, using NVidia's custom systemd suspend service, ..).

I'm using the NVidia card as part of the second seat of a multi-seat setup (using loginctl and lightdm). This may be related, as the second seat doesn't allow Virtual Terminal switching, which the NVidia custom systemd suspend service seems to be using to trick XOrg into reinitializing.

(After many hours, I've found a workaround. I'm posting this to save others the headache, and perhaps to discover a less hacky solution.)

Answer (score 1):

After coming back from suspend `xrandr --auto` can be used to force Xorg te reinitialize its output. In some cases, it appears necessary to do a `xrandr --off` first. The difficulty with automating this is knowing where the Xauthority file for the logged in user is. Lightdm has it own authority file though, which also provides access and is in a standard location. Also, the second seat is sometimes `DISPLAY=:0` and sometimes `DISPLAY=:1`.

Here's a script you can modify to use the right OUTPUT device and store as `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/resume-seat1`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT=HDMI-0

for DISPLAY in :0 :1 ; do
  export DISPLAY
  export XAUTHORITY=/run/lightdm/root/$DISPLAY

  case "$1" in
    pre)
      xrandr --output $OUTPUT --off
      ;;
    post)
      xrandr --output $OUTPUT --auto
      ;;
  esac
done
```

You'll need to make the script executable.

```bash
chmod a+x /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/resume-seat1
```

Comment: +1. This stopped *light-locker* giving me a black screen. However it showed up as a tiny square on the top left. Typing the password and hitting `Enter` allows me to log in. The actual fix for me was to uninstall (the no longer maintained) `light-locker`, and instead use `dm-tool lock` to lock the screen on suspend.